# Meaning of "a few lost beams of latent light"

Tags: meaning

What does *a few lost beams of latent light* mean?

> I think it's summer still outside
>   **A few lost beams of latent light**
>    – [moi Caprice](http://www.lyricsvip.com/moi-Caprice/The-Art-of-Kissing-Properly-Lyrics.html)

Comment: If you wanted to know what 'latent' means, you should look up a dictionary.  If you are unsure of the poetic intent of the writer, you could ask on writersSE. ELU generally does not encourage pedantic topics in QA.

Comment: Indeed, poetic interpretation is off topic for here.

Comment: or literature.SE, if song lyrics count there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Latent* means 'hidden' or 'concealed'. The writer seems to be using the word to say that the beams of light were very faint.

Comment: plus one. that is it.

Comment: Indeed, summer days are long – sounds like the end of the day to me.  I suppose the author could have used _dying_ light, too, but probably liked the alliterativeness of _latent_.

Comment: @J.R.: A clear missed opportunity to use the word _crepuscular_! Even though it doesn't fit the meter or alliterate.

Answer (score 1):

- A collection of few rays of light constitutes a [beam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_beam).
- *Latent* means "Present but not evident or active."
- So the writer talks of some faint sun rays.